# How to view asp.net Identity methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I would like to be able to view some of the methods from an asp.net Identity application.Consider this line if code from a controller:

`var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);`

When I try to find by definition (F12) on `FindByNameAsync`, it takes me to a tab called `UserManager[from metadata]` and displays only the following:

`public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName);`

Why am I unable to view the actual method? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The app has only a reference to the module or library that has the implementation for FIndByNameAsync, and thus only infers the call from the metadata in the calling assembly.

Comment: Decompiling the code? not sure if Microsoft allows you to do it

Comment: Source code for version 2.2 is here: http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/. And link to the v3.x is linked below on Github.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of libraries aren't shown when you use the 'find definition' shortcut.
If you want the source, have a look at the AspNetCore Identity code [on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the link, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It won't allow you to view the code as it is an ASP.NET Core class.

You can check the latest code of **UserManager.cs** class in below GitHub website link

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs

Hope this will you..